# jQuery.timer how to get current value in php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm using this jquery timer to collect time spent while it is running.

https://github.com/walmik/timer.jquery

http://jquerytimer.com/

How to I get the current value into a php variable?

I'd like to have a Button that when clicked saves the current value in the input field.

Problem is that when I wrap the input in a form and expect to use a $_POST['fieldID'] to collect the value it disables the jqueryTimer.

I can pull the input field out of the form but what is the best means to collect the current value presented with jQuery? Write a script addition that populates a hidden field with the current value from jQueryTimer?

It would be ideal if the value available to php could also be updated if the Pause and restart is invoked.

EDIT TO SHOW CODE:

```
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timer.jquery/0.6.5/timer.jquery.min.js'></script>

<!--    http://jquerytimer.com/-->
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var hasTimer = false;
        // Init timer start
        $('.start-timer-btn').on('click', function() {
            hasTimer = true;
            $('.timer').timer({
                editable: true
            });
            $(this).addClass('d-none');
            $('.pause-timer-btn, .remove-timer-btn').removeClass('d-none');
        });

        // Init timer resume
        $('.resume-timer-btn').on('click', function() {
            $('.timer').timer('resume');
            $(this).addClass('d-none');
            $('.pause-timer-btn, .remove-timer-btn').removeClass('d-none');
        });


        // Init timer pause
        $('.pause-timer-btn').on('click', function() {
            $('.timer').timer('pause');
            $('.resume-timer-btn').removeClass('d-none');
        });

        // Remove timer
        $('.remove-timer-btn').on('click', function() {
            hasTimer = false;
            $('.timer').timer('remove');
            $(this).addClass('d-none');
            $('.start-timer-btn').removeClass('d-none');
            $('.pause-timer-btn, .resume-timer-btn').addClass('d-none');
        });

        // Additional focus event for this demo
        $('.timer').on('focus', function() {
            if(hasTimer) {
                $('.pause-timer-btn').addClass('d-none');
                $('.resume-timer-btn').removeClass('d-none');
            }
        });

        // Additional blur event for this demo
        $('.timer').on('blur', function() {
            if(hasTimer) {
                $('.pause-timer-btn').removeClass('d-none');
                $('.resume-timer-btn').addClass('d-none');
            }
        });
    });

$('.timer').each(function() {
console.log( this.val() );
});
</script>
```

html:

```
    <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-md-3'>
                <input type='text' name='timer' class='form-control timer' placeholder='0 sec'  id="timer" />
            </div>
            <div class='col-md-9'>
                <button class='btn btn-success start-timer-btn'>Start</button>
                <button class='btn btn-success resume-timer-btn d-none'>Resume</button>
                <button class='btn btn-secondary pause-timer-btn d-none'>Pause</button>
                <button class='btn btn-danger remove-timer-btn d-none'>Remove Timer</button>
            </div>
        </div>
<form action="" method="" id="form1">
<input type="submit">
<input name="currentTime" type="hidden" id="currentTime" value="needed">
</form>
```

GOAL: Be able to have the current value as a php var so it can be submitted to a database.

Prior attempts found that if the input was within a form tag it no longer worked.

Idea in consideration is updating the hidden input field on some click which would allow it to be used in PHP to Insert to DB.

Comment: Please show us some code which you've tried, so that we have a reference point to start from. It's somewhat unclear what you want to achieve.

Comment: Why not using ajax post? https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: You say: _"...saves the current value in the input field."_. What do you mean by _"saves"_? To save the current timer value in a db table upon some form submission? Please note that a form submission refreshes the page, or redirects to another page. Therefore, all informations related to the timer in the current page will be lost.

Comment: Yes, the goal is to be able to save to a database. The problem is the form logic does not allow access to the current value presented in the input field. Yes, if the form submits it may (not sure) cause the timer to reset.

Comment: I've updated the linked page to use @Depzor 's suggestion (jquery.post). But no results so far and still not sure how to get the value into something I can submit via php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my proposal. It's indeed based on performing an ajax request. A form is, of course, not needed in this case. As already commented, by submitting a form, all informations related to the timer in the current page would be lost, because the submit would refresh the whole page where the timer resides, or would even redirect to another page - if so demanded.

You can run my code as it is, but you need to change the db connection credentials and the db table related infos in the *INSERT* sql statement.

The timer resides in *index.php*. The server-side saving operation is performed in *saveTime.php* - I used the PDO extension for it. The database connection is created in *connection.php*.

On the client-side, the saving operation - *saveTime()* - is started by clicking the *.save-timer-btn* button, or the *.pause-timer-btn* button. But you can call *saveTime()* on the events of your choice.

If the posted timer value is not defined, the PHP code sends a response header, which triggers the *error* function of the ajax request. The *error* function will then display a bootstrap alert of type *danger*. The same applies if the passed timer state is not recognised by PHP. If the saving operation succeeds, a *success* alert will be displayed.

Note: My codes don't rely on your codes, but they are just slightly different. This is because I used the last version (*0.7.1*) of the timer and the code used in the demo from [jquerytimer.com](http://jquerytimer.com/). I suggest you to pay attention to each code line. Sorry :-) I also used the version *3.3.7* of Bootstrap.

Note: For proper error reporting/handling you could read [this](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting) and [this](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#errors) articles, since I didn't implement it in my PHP code.

#### index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes" />
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags must come first in the head -->

        <title>Demo - Timer</title>

        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timer.jquery/0.7.1/timer.jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var hasTimer = false;

                /**
                 * Save the current timer value.
                 * 
                 * Performs an ajax request to the server, which will 
                 * save the timer value in a database table and return
                 * a corresponding message.
                 */
                function saveTime() {
                    $.ajax({
                        method: 'post',
                        dataType: 'html',
                        url: 'saveTime.php',
                        data: {
                            'time': $('.timer').data('seconds'),
                            'state': $('.timer').data('state')
                        },
                        success: function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                            displayAlert('success', response);
                        },
                        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            /*
                             * If the status code of the response is the custom one 
                             * defined by me, the developer, in saveTime.php, then I 
                             * can display the corresponding error message. Otherwise, 
                             * the displayed message will be a general user-friendly 
                             * one - so, that no system-related infos will be shown.
                             */
                            var message = (jqXHR.status === 420)
                                    ? jqXHR.statusText
                                    : 'An error occurred during your request. Please try again.';

                            displayAlert('danger', message);
                        },
                        complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                            //...
                        }
                    });
                }

                /**
                 * Display a bootstrap alert.
                 * 
                 * @param type string success|info|warning|danger.
                 * @param message string Alert message.
                 * @return void
                 */
                function displayAlert(type, message) {
                    var alert = '<div class="alert alert-' + type + ' alert-dismissible" role="alert">'
                            + '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">'
                            + '<span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>'
                            + '</button>'
                            + '<span>' + message + '</span>'
                            + '</div>';

                    $('.messages').html(alert);
                }

                // Init timer start
                $('.save-timer-btn').on('click', function () {
                    saveTime();
                });

                // Init timer start
                $('.start-timer-btn').on('click', function () {
                    hasTimer = true;
                    $('.timer').timer({
                        editable: true
                    });
                    $(this).addClass('hidden');
                    $('.pause-timer-btn, .remove-timer-btn').removeClass('hidden');
                });

                // Init timer resume
                $('.resume-timer-btn').on('click', function () {
                    $('.timer').timer('resume');
                    $(this).addClass('hidden');
                    $('.pause-timer-btn, .remove-timer-btn').removeClass('hidden');
                });

                // Init timer pause
                $('.pause-timer-btn').on('click', function () {
                    $('.timer').timer('pause');
                    $(this).addClass('hidden');
                    $('.resume-timer-btn').removeClass('hidden');

                    saveTime();
                });

                // Remove timer. Leaves the display intact.
                $('.remove-timer-btn').on('click', function () {
                    hasTimer = false;
                    $('.timer').timer('remove');
                    $(this).addClass('hidden');
                    $('.start-timer-btn').removeClass('hidden');
                    $('.pause-timer-btn, .resume-timer-btn').addClass('hidden');
                });

                // Additional focus event for this demo
                $('.timer').on('focus', function () {
                    if (hasTimer) {
                        $('.pause-timer-btn').addClass('hidden');
                        $('.resume-timer-btn').removeClass('hidden');
                    }
                });

                // Additional blur event for this demo
                $('.timer').on('blur', function () {
                    if (hasTimer) {
                        $('.pause-timer-btn').removeClass('hidden');
                        $('.resume-timer-btn').addClass('hidden');
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>

        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                padding: 50px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <h4>
                        Timer Demo
                    </h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6 messages"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <input type="text" id="timer" name="timer" class="form-control timer" placeholder="0 sec">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success start-timer-btn">
                        Start
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success resume-timer-btn hidden">
                        Resume
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn pause-timer-btn hidden">
                        Pause
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove-timer-btn hidden">
                        Remove Timer
                    </button>

                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary save-timer-btn">
                        Save timer value
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

#### saveTime.php

```
<?php

require 'connection.php';

// Validate the timer value.
if (!isset($_POST['time']) || empty($_POST['time'])) {
    /*
     * This response header triggers the ajax error because the status 
     * code begins with 4xx (which corresponds to the client errors).
     * I defined 420 as the custom status code. You can choose whatever
     * code between 401 and 499 which is not officially assigned, e.g.
     * which is marked as "Unassigned" in the official HTTP Status Code Registry.
     * See the link.
     * 
     * @link https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xhtml HTTP Status Code Registry.
     */
    header('HTTP/1.1 420 No time value defined. Did you start the timer?');
    exit();
}

// Validate the timer state.
if (!isset($_POST['state']) || empty($_POST['state'])) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 420 No timer state recognized. Did you start the timer?');
    exit();
}

// Read the posted values.
$time = $_POST['time'];
$state = $_POST['state']; /* The state of the timer when the saving operation was triggered. */

/*
 * Save the timer value in a db table using PDO library.
 */
$sql = 'INSERT INTO my_timer_table (
            time
        ) VALUES (
            :time
        )';
$statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute([
    ':time' => $time,
]);

// Print success message.
echo 'Time (' . $time . ' seconds) successfully saved when timer was ' . $state . '.';
exit();
```

#### connection.php

```
<?php

// Db configs.
define('HOST', 'localhost');
define('PORT', 3306);
define('DATABASE', 'yourDb');
define('USERNAME', 'yourUsername');
define('PASSWORD', 'yourPassword');
define('CHARSET', 'utf8');

$connection = new PDO(
        sprintf('mysql:host=%s;port=%s;dbname=%s;charset=%s', HOST, PORT, DATABASE, CHARSET)
        , USERNAME
        , PASSWORD
        , [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => FALSE,
    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => FALSE,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
        ]
);
```

#### *Create table* syntax

```
CREATE TABLE `my_timer_table` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `time` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: I've made some changes to your code , temp disabling the Insert and updating to Bootstrap 4. I'm now trying to use ajax to send two more values to the saveTime.php page. I've created a new post to help others learn the logic of ajax:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49367881/jquery-timer-ajax-send-multiple-form-values-to-secondary-page