# jQuery.Timer Ajax send multiple form values to secondary page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm using this jquery timer to collect time spent while it is running.

https://github.com/walmik/timer.jquery
http://jquerytimer.com/

In a prior Stack Overflow post we were able to Post to another page the current accumulated time using jQuery Ajax ([jQuery.timer how to get current value in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49327105/jquery-timer-how-to-get-current-value-in-php)). Many thinks to @Dakis

It seems our current solution is trying to save on any Stop and Restart of the Timer. It only needs to do a Save to DB routine IF the “Save Time and Notes” button is selected.

I’ve been researching jQuery Ajax and understand that a key/value pair is needed to be sent to the server/receiving page. I understand the first value identifies the target from which to get the "key", but I could not get a clear understanding of proper formatting for the second “value”.
**'task': $('.ta_tasks').data('task’)** does not seem to be passing the value as expected.

I’ve added a TextArea with an ID of “ta_tasks” and appended the current working AJAX with:

```
data: {
  'time': $('.timer').data('seconds'),
  'state': $('.timer').data('state'),
  'task': $('.ta_tasks').data('task’)
```

On the receiving page I added a simple alert to see if the value is being received but it is not. If I can figure out how to properly send the contents of the TextArea I could also figure out how to submit a value from the “Save Time and Notes” button so that a Pause and Restart will not also submit to the database.

Working page:  http://sgdesign.com/timer2.php

**Parent page script:**

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timer.jquery/0.7.1/timer.jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var hasTimer = false;

            /**
             * Save the current timer value.
             * 
             * Performs an ajax request to the server, which will 
             * save the timer value in a database table and return
             * a corresponding message.
             */
            function saveTime() {
                $.ajax({
                    method: 'post',
                    dataType: 'html',
                    url: 'saveTime.php',
                    data: {
                        'time': $('.timer').data('seconds'),
                        'state': $('.timer').data('state'),
            'task': $('.ta_tasks').data('task')
                    },
                    success: function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                        displayAlert('success', response);
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        /*
                         * If the status code of the response is the custom one 
                         * defined by me, the developer, in saveTime.php, then I 
                         * can display the corresponding error message. Otherwise, 
                         * the displayed message will be a general user-friendly 
                         * one - so, that no system-related infos will be shown.
                         */
                        var message = (jqXHR.status === 420)
                                ? jqXHR.statusText
                                : 'An error occurred during your request. Please try again.';

                        displayAlert('danger', message);
                    },
                    complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                        //...
                    }
                });
            }

            /**
             * Display a bootstrap alert.
             * 
             * @param type string success|info|warning|danger.
             * @param message string Alert message.
             * @return void
             */
            function displayAlert(type, message) {
                var alert = '<div class="alert alert-' + type + ' alert-dismissible" role="alert">'
                        + '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">'
                        + '<span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>'
                        + '</button>'
                        + '<span>' + message + '</span>'
                        + '</div>';

                $('.messages').html(alert);
            }

            // Init timer start
            $('.save-timer-btn').on('click', function () {
                saveTime();
            });

            // Init timer start
            $('.start-timer-btn').on('click', function () {
                hasTimer = true;
                $('.timer').timer({
                    editable: true
                });
                $(this).addClass('d-none');
                $('.pause-timer-btn').removeClass('d-none');
            });

            // Init timer resume
            $('.resume-timer-btn').on('click', function () {
                $('.timer').timer('resume');
                $(this).addClass('d-none');
                $('.pause-timer-btn').removeClass('d-none');
            });

            // Init timer pause
            $('.pause-timer-btn').on('click', function () {
                $('.timer').timer('pause');
                $(this).addClass('d-none');
                $('.resume-timer-btn').removeClass('d-none');

                saveTime();
            });

            // Remove timer. Leaves the display intact.
            $('.remove-timer-btn').on('click', function () {
                hasTimer = false;
                $('.timer').timer('remove');
                $(this).addClass('d-none');
                $('.start-timer-btn').removeClass('d-none');
                $('.pause-timer-btn, .resume-timer-btn').addClass('d-none');
            });

            // Additional focus event for this demo
            $('.timer').on('focus', function () {
                if (hasTimer) {
                    $('.pause-timer-btn').addClass('d-none');
                    $('.resume-timer-btn').removeClass('hidden');
                }
            });

            // Additional blur event for this demo
            $('.timer').on('blur', function () {
                if (hasTimer) {
                    $('.pause-timer-btn').removeClass('d-none');
                    $('.resume-timer-btn').addClass('d-none');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

**Target Page contents:**

```
<?php
// Price per hour variable
$cost = 50;

# require 'connection.php';

// Validate the timer value.
if (!isset($_POST['time']) || empty($_POST['time'])) {
/*
 * This response header triggers the ajax error because the status 
 * code begins with 4xx (which corresponds to the client errors).
 * I defined 420 as the custom status code. You can choose whatever
 * code between 401 and 499 which is not officially assigned, e.g.
 * which is marked as "Unassigned" in the official HTTP Status Code Registry.
 * See the link.
 * 
 * @link https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xhtml HTTP Status Code Registry.
 */
header('HTTP/1.1 420 No time value defined. Did you start the timer?');
exit();
}

// Validate the timer state.
if (!isset($_POST['state']) || empty($_POST['state'])) {
header('HTTP/1.1 420 No timer state recognized. Did you start the timer?');
exit();
}

// Read the posted values.
$time = $_POST['time'];
$state = $_POST['state']; /* The state of the timer when the saving operation was triggered. */
$task = $_POST['ta_tasks'];
$r = $cost / 3600 * $time;
$rate = round($r, 2);

/*
 * Save the timer value in a db table using PDO library.
 */
/* $sql = 'INSERT INTO my_timer_table (
        time
    ) VALUES (
        :time
    )';
$statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute([
':time' => $time,
]);

// Print success message.
echo 'Time (' . $time . ' seconds) successfully saved when timer was ' . $state . '.';
exit();  */
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script>
    var a =  "<?php echo $task; ?>";
    alert ('task: ' + a);
</script>
</head>

<body>
<?php function secondsToTime($seconds) {
$dtF = new \DateTime('@0');
$dtT = new \DateTime("@$seconds");
return $dtF->diff($dtT)->format('%h hours, %i minutes and %s seconds');
// return $dtF->diff($dtT)->format('%a days, %h hours, %i minutes and %s seconds');
}
?>
<?php echo secondsToTime($time);
echo '<br>'; 
echo 'Tasks: '.$task .'<br>'; 
echo 'Cost: $'. $rate;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

**Goal Summary**
Proper formatting of data in: 'task': $('.ta_tasks').data('task’)
Understanding of Why so as to learn how to also transfer when the 'Save Time and Notes" button to invoke saving Cost and Notes to DB

[image: generic image of page result]

Comment: `$('.ta_tasks').val()` will get the contents of the text area.

Comment: @WildBeard will it be received as a post value " .val() "? Because in testing my Alert still is empty

$task = $_POST['ta_tasks'];

 <script>
  var a =  "<?php echo $task; ?>";
  alert ('task: ' + a);
 </script>

Comment: You're sending the key `task` in `data: { 'time': .., 'state': .., 'task': ..}` so in your PHP it should be `$_POST['task']` not `$_POST['ta_tasks']`.

Comment: :-( none of the suggestions work. I understand Wild Beard noting that the Post value is actually $_POST[‘task’] because of the construction in the AJAX script. I also understand Ivans post noting the lack of ta_tasks as a class and how adding the class name or changing the reference to use the ID (#ta_tasks) should properly bind the object. But none of these return a result to the Alert which is the current test mechanism.

Comment: On your website you're still using `$('.ta_task').data('task')` instead of `.val()`.

Comment: I'm testing on a new page soas to not confuse prior info posts.
Using proper ID targeting and your suggestion (Wildbread) of val() properly transfers the data.         'task': $('#ta_tasks').val()        http://sgdesign.com/timer3.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't define functions inside `$(document).ready`. Bring them outside.

Functions in PHP should reside only in pages destined for this purpose. See [PSR-1 Side Effects](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/#23-side-effects). In principle you should definitely read: PSR-1 and PSR-2. Optional, especially PSR-4.

When you try to read a value sent through ajax, then you should read the value, not the CSS selector. So: Wrong: `$task = $_POST['ta_tasks'];`, correct: `$task = $_POST['task'];`.

Before validating posted values (on top of the page *saveTime.php*) you shouldn't declare any variables or do other things - so to say. So no `$cost = 50;` before validations, but after them. Still, if you want to define constants for *saveTime.php*, then better bring them in another file, which you can include.

In this case, the `data()` method is a proprietary method of http://jquerytimer.com ! You can use it to fetch some values (timer value, timer state, etc). But, in order to fetch the value of a html control you need to use `val()`, or `text()`, or `innerHtml`, etc. In a word: native js or jquery methods/functions. So, use like this:

```
data: {
    'time': $('.timer').data('seconds'),
    'state': $('.timer').data('state'),
    'task': $('#ta_tasks').val()
}
```

Do you see the selector (`'#ta_tasks'`)? It references an id (because of `#`). You used `.ta_tasks`, therefore referencing a class name. Which you didn't define.

Better: use the *camelCase* naming convention for html id's and names, and the "hyphen-separated" form for css classes:

```
data: {
    'time': $('.timer').data('seconds'),
    'state': $('.timer').data('state'),
    'task': $('#ta_tasks').val()
}

//...

<textarea id="taTasks" name="taTasks" class="form-control" rows="4">Doh!</textarea>
```

Avoid as much as possible referencing php code from javascript or css code. If you need a php value inside a javascript code, then pass it through a javascript function - as argument, or save the php value inside an attribute of a html control and read it through referencing the attribute by js/jquery methods/functions. As an example, see the code in *saveTime.php*, which saves the *task* value in a hidden input and alerts it from js code.

---

#### index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes" />
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags must come first in the head -->

        <title>Demo - Timer</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timer.jquery/0.7.1/timer.jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var hasTimer = false;

                // Init timer start
                $('.save-timer-btn').on('click', function () {
                    saveTime();
                });

                // Init timer start
                $('.start-timer-btn').on('click', function () {
                    hasTimer = true;
                    $('.timer').timer({
                        editable: true
                    });
                    $(this).addClass('d-none');
                    $('.pause-timer-btn').removeClass('d-none');
                });

                // Init timer resume
                $('.resume-timer-btn').on('click', function () {
                    $('.timer').timer('resume');
                    $(this).addClass('d-none');
                    $('.pause-timer-btn').removeClass('d-none');
                });

                // Init timer pause
                $('.pause-timer-btn').on('click', function () {
                    $('.timer').timer('pause');
                    $(this).addClass('d-none');
                    $('.resume-timer-btn').removeClass('d-none');

                    saveTime();
                });

                // Remove timer. Leaves the display intact.
                $('.remove-timer-btn').on('click', function () {
                    hasTimer = false;
                    $('.timer').timer('remove');
                    $(this).addClass('d-none');
                    $('.start-timer-btn').removeClass('d-none');
                    $('.pause-timer-btn, .resume-timer-btn').addClass('d-none');
                });

                // Additional focus event for this demo
                $('.timer').on('focus', function () {
                    if (hasTimer) {
                        $('.pause-timer-btn').addClass('d-none');
                        $('.resume-timer-btn').removeClass('d-none');
                    }
                });

                // Additional blur event for this demo
                $('.timer').on('blur', function () {
                    if (hasTimer) {
                        $('.pause-timer-btn').removeClass('d-none');
                        $('.resume-timer-btn').addClass('d-none');
                    }
                });
            });

            /**
             * Save the current timer value.
             * 
             * Performs an ajax request to the server, which will 
             * save the timer value in a database table and return
             * a corresponding message.
             */
            function saveTime() {
                $.ajax({
                    method: 'post',
                    dataType: 'html',
                    url: 'saveTime.php',
                    data: {
                        'time': $('.timer').data('seconds'),
                        'state': $('.timer').data('state'),
                        'task': $('#taTasks').val()
                    },
                    success: function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                        displayAlert('success', response);
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        var message = (jqXHR.status === 420)
                                ? jqXHR.statusText
                                : 'An error occurred during your request. Please try again.';

                        displayAlert('danger', message);
                    },
                    complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                        //...
                    }
                });
            }

            /**
             * Display a bootstrap alert.
             * 
             * @param type string success|info|warning|danger.
             * @param message string Alert message.
             * @return void
             */
            function displayAlert(type, message) {
                var alert = '<div class="alert alert-' + type + ' alert-dismissible" role="alert">'
                        + '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">'
                        + '<span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>'
                        + '</button>'
                        + '<span>' + message + '</span>'
                        + '</div>';

                $('.messages').html(alert);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <h4>
                        Timer Demo 2
                    </h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6 messages"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <input type="text" id="timer" name="timer" class="form-control timer" placeholder="0 sec">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success start-timer-btn">
                        Start
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success resume-timer-btn d-none">
                        Resume
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger pause-timer-btn d-none">
                        Pause
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove-timer-btn d-none">
                        Remove Timer
                    </button>

                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary save-timer-btn">
                        Save Time and Notes
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row mt-1">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <lable for="taTasks">Notes to accompany task:</lable>        
                    <textarea id="taTasks" name="taTasks" class="form-control" rows="4">Doh!</textarea>
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

#### saveTime.php

```
<?php
require_once 'functions.php';

// Validate the timer value.
if (!isset($_POST['time']) || empty($_POST['time'])) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 420 No time value defined. Did you start the timer?');
    exit();
}

// Validate the timer state.
if (!isset($_POST['state']) || empty($_POST['state'])) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 420 No timer state recognized. Did you start the timer?');
    exit();
}

// Validate the task.
if (!isset($_POST['task']) || empty($_POST['task'])) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 420 No task value received.');
    exit();
}

// Price per hour variable
$cost = 50;

// Read the posted values.
$time = $_POST['time'];
$state = $_POST['state']; /* The state of the timer when the saving operation was triggered. */
$task = $_POST['task'];
$r = $cost / 3600 * $time;
$rate = round($r, 2);
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alertTask();
    });

    function alertTask() {
        var task = $('#task').val();
        alert(task);
    }
</script>
<input type="hidden" id="task" name="task" value="<?php echo $task; ?>">
<?php
echo secondsToTime($time);
echo '<br>';
echo 'Tasks: ' . $task . '<br>';
echo 'Cost: $' . $rate;
?>
```

#### functions.php

```
<?php

function secondsToTime($seconds) {
    $dtF = new \DateTime('@0');
    $dtT = new \DateTime("@$seconds");
    return $dtF->diff($dtT)->format('%h hours, %i minutes and %s seconds');
    // return $dtF->diff($dtT)->format('%a days, %h hours, %i minutes and %s seconds');
}
```

---

**Edit 1:** In *index.php*, I brought the js functions outside of `$(document).ready`. I forgot to do it earlier.

**Edit 2:** Changed `hidden` to `d-none` in

```
$('.resume-timer-btn').removeClass('hidden');
```

**Edit 3:** I found the problem about which I commented. It was in my *saveTime.php* code: I loaded the jquery library, but it was already loaded in *index.php*. More of it: since you are loading the content of *saveTime.php* in a html page (*index.php*) which already has all resources loaded, you don't need to structure the *saveTime.php* as a whole structured html (with doctype, head, body, etc). It is completely enough to just define the content and script tags that you need. So, I reedited *saveTime.php* correspondingly.

Comment: In my other example, set so as to not confuse the initial link, I did change to 'task': $('#ta_tasks').val() as per suggestions from Wild Beard and van Karaman

Comment: you also saw that the original code was going to submit to DB each time the timer was paused and restarted? I plan on passing a value from the Save Time and Notes button when the DB Insert is actually needed.

Comment: Yes I saw. Ok. Note that something is not quite right with the code in its current form. See what happens when you click twice on `.save-timer-btn`. It's up to you now :-) Have fun. If you need to ask anything, don't hesitate.

Answer (score 1):

textarea don't have `ta_tasks` class, u use `id` and it doesn't have html5 `data object`, correct to `$("#ta_tasks").val()`.

Answer (score 0):

check your ajax request data that you re sending and the one you are getting in your saveTime.php, you are sending 'task' and receiving 'ta_task' in saveTime.php

```js
$.ajax({
   method: 'post',
   dataType: 'html',
   url: 'saveTime.php',
   data: {
        'time': $('.timer').data('seconds'),
       'state': $('.timer').data('state'),
       'ta_task': $('.ta_tasks').data('task')
   },
                    //other codes here
```

```html
//saveTime.php
//now get the value with 'ta_task'
$task = $_POST['ta_task'];
```